# MySQL query count of grandchildren with where clause

Tags: mysql

Ok, I have looked and I cant seem to find an answer to this and I really need some help.

I have 3 tables:

```
m(id, name), p(id, m_id, name), t(id, p_id, date, type, status)
```

They are joined as:

```
m.id = p.m_id
p.id = t.p_id
```

I need to get a count of t.type where t.type = approved
grouped by m.id and by p.id

This is what I have so far, but I get errors with "subquery return multiple rows" or I just get a total count that is applied to all records.

```
SELECT
          m.`id`,
          m.`company`,
          (SELECT COUNT(t.`type`) 
          FROM t 
          INNER JOIN p on p.`id`=t.`p_id` 
          INNER JOIN m on p.`m_id`= m.`id`  
          WHERE t.`type`='approved' GROUP BY m.`id`) AS `app`
        FROM m
          INNER JOIN p
            ON m.`id` = p.`m_id`
          INNER JOIN t
            ON p.`id` = t.`p_id`
        WHERE t.`date` BETWEEN '2015-11-01 00:00:00' AND NOW() 
        GROUP BY m.`id`
        ORDER BY m.`company
```

I am completely lost here.

Comment: If you get "subquery return multiple rows" then you have to correct that subquery; prove that query alone and see if it gives you the expected result. PS: you should include in your post the structure of your tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try and change your query to use COUNT instead which will help you avoid subquery.  Something like the query below should get you the results you want.

```
SELECT
   m.`id`,
   m.`company`,
   COUNT(IF(t.`type` = 'approved', t.`type`, NULL)) AS `app`,
   COUNT(IF(t.`type` = 'declined', t.`type`, NULL)) AS `dec`
FROM m
   INNER JOIN p
      ON m.`id` = p.`m_id`
   INNER JOIN t
      ON p.`id` = t.`p_id`
WHERE t.`date` BETWEEN '2015-11-01 00:00:00' AND NOW() 
   AND t.`type` IN ('approved', 'declined')
GROUP BY m.`id`
ORDER BY m.`company
```

Comment: Unfortunately no, The I need to actually have 3 COUNT() each with their own where clause.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 3 count each with their own where clause?  Do you mean you want to show different counts for different m and p?  If that is the case, you would just add to the GROUP BY the p.`id`

Comment: so, 1 count would be COUNT(t.id) where t.type = 'approved', another would be COUNT(t.id) where t.type="declined", and another would be COUNT(t.id) where t.type = "pending" each using the same where t.date between.

Comment: Try the updated query above.  You can use COUNT with the IF clause to count only types matching approve or decline.

Comment: You sir are the man, the myth and the legend, my new found hero!